# how to use BrowsableAttribute Class for displaying in propertygrid

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

I need to display these srings 'm_nullPolicy' and 'm_nullVersion' in properties window ,i mean in property grid . as of now it is displaying
in UI.When i did a search i can see BrowsableAttribute Class will do that but i dont know how to implement it here, can anybody guide me here

This is the code to display value in UI

```
if (Data.ResourcePolicy == null)
                            {
                                if (Data.AgentVersion == null)
                                {
                                    SubItems.Add(ResourcePolicyAvailSystemsLVI.m_nullString);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    SubItems.Add(m_nullPolicy);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                SubItems.Add(Data.ResourcePolicy.Name);
                            }
                            if (Data.AgentVersion == null || Data.AgentVersion.Equals("0.0.0.0"))
                            {
                                SubItems.Add(ResourcePolicySystemsControl.m_nullVersion);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                SubItems.Add(Data.AgentVersion);
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

When deling with the PropertyGrid manually, the BrowsableAttribute does not apply.

By manually I mean, when inserting items on the property grid one by one.

You can however, use the automated way... that is, using an object that contains properties with the BrowsableAttribute and assign the object to the SelectedObject property.

**Try the following:**

Create a class, with some properties, for example:

```
    class MyClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [BrowsableAttribute(false)]
        public string InvisibleProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

Create a form with a property grid on it.

Now, instantiate the class and assign it to SelectedObject property, maybe in the form load event:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = new MyClass();
    }
```

In this example, the property grid will show the `Name` property, but not the `InvisibleProperty`.

Comment: The property grid has a property called `SelectedObject` that you may use to assign an entire object, that you want to be edited.

Comment: let me try frm my side ,if not possible i will respond